# 1D heat equation separation of variables with split initial datum

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

While solving following PDE I stumbled upon a problem in the last step:

$\ u_t-16u_{xx}=0, x\in(0,1), t \gt 0 $

$\ u(t,0)=u(t,1)=0, t\gt 0 $

$\ u(0,x)=\begin{cases}
x^2,  & x\lt \frac{1}{2} \\
(1-x)^2, & x\geq \frac{1}{2} \end{cases} $

Now, using separation of variables I find:

$\ u(x,t)=\sum_{i=0}^n c_n\cdot e^{-k^2 \pi^216t}\cdot\sin(n\pi x) $

Usually, if the initial datum wasn't split I would proceed with comparison of coefficients to deduce existing $ c_n $ coefficients but I see no way of applying it here. Am I making a mistake in the separation of variable process or is there a way for solving cases where the initial datum is split depending on x?

Hints and solutions are appreciated!

Comment: You should see the set of $\sin(n\pi x)$ for all $n$ as a base of the Hilbert space in which you are working. I don't remember exactly how it works, but taking the inner product of $u$ with the various elements of your base gets you $c_n$. The fact that your datum is split makes it so that your inner product becomes a sum of two integrals instead of one, but the principle remains the same.

Comment: You just need to calculate the Fourier transform of the $u(0,x)$ and plug in $t=0$ in your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the computations up. You have

\begin{align} 
u(x,t) &= \sum_{k} c_{k} e^{-16 k^{2} \pi^{2} t} \sin (k \pi x) \\ 
\implies u(x,0) &= \sum_{k} c_{k} \sin (k \pi x) \\
&= \begin{cases}
x^2,  & x\lt \frac{1}{2} \\
(1-x)^2, & x\geq \frac{1}{2} \end{cases}
\end{align}

Taking the inner product with $\sin(n \pi x)$ on both sides over $[0,1/2]$ gives

\begin{align}
\sum_{k} c_{k} \int_{0}^{1/2} \sin (k \pi x) \sin (n \pi x) dx &= \begin{cases}
0,  & k \ne n \\
c_{n}/4, & k = n \end{cases} \\
&= \int_{0}^{1/2} x^{2} \sin (n \pi x) dx \\
\implies c_{n} &= 4 \int_{0}^{1/2} x^{2} \sin (n \pi x) dx
\end{align}

and you need to integrate by parts to get the explicit form of the coefficients $c_{n}$. Similarly,

\begin{align}
\sum_{k} c_{k} \int_{1/2}^{1} \sin (k \pi x) \sin (n \pi x) dx &= \begin{cases}
0,  & k \ne n \\
c_{n}/4, & k = n \end{cases} \\
&= \int_{1/2}^{1} (1 - x)^{2} \sin (n \pi x) dx \\
\implies c_{n} &= 4 \int_{1/2}^{1} (1 - x)^{2} \sin (n \pi x) dx
\end{align}

Then the final solution will be

\begin{align}
u(x,t) &= \sum_{k} \left( 4 \int_{0}^{1/2} x^{2} \sin (k \pi x) dx \right) e^{-16 k^{2} \pi^{2} t} \sin (k \pi x) \\
&+ \sum_{k} \left( 4 \int_{1/2}^{1} (1 - x)^{2} \sin (k \pi x) dx \right) e^{-16 k^{2} \pi^{2} t} \sin (k \pi x)
\end{align}